# How to embed content from external sites into my site

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, blogs

I am currently building a website (not for any profit but just as a personal project) that I want to be as a sort of "directory" with a bunch of different posts from different websites (think of it more like a tutorial website), however I want the posts to show up within my site and don't want to be directed away from my site because then you have to go back to the directory to find more posts.

My initial idea was to have all the posts internally just pop up with the content in an iframe, this worked great for smaller sites but a lot of big sites have iframe blockers (understandably to stop people making profit off of their content).

Is there a way I can embed these posts in my site?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. The only way to make this work, is if the post or element from a website supports iframe data. It is like when embedded a YouTube video into a website: they would give you the iframe code to put in your website. It will only work if the developers for the website have created iframe code to use.

For an example, this would be how you can Embed a YouTube video (only works if you are using a computer). This also may work for other platforms like Instagram or Twitter:

Step 1: Click share below the video
[image: click share]
Step 2: Click the embed button
[image: click embed]
Step 3: Copy and paste the code in your website and style it however you want
[image: copy and paste code]

Answer (score 0):

If the websites you want the posts from have an RSS feed (or another kind of API) set up, you can [build an RSS Reader](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-rss-feeds-in-javascript/) app.
Note that a lot of sites won't expose their whole articles in the RSS feed but only summaries.